# Geometry of USB Memory - heads per cylinder is 124

Tags: usb, hard-drive, fdisk, testdisk

i have a USB Stick,
and this stick has some problems,
how to set up for it proper geometry

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 4009 MB / 3824 MiB - CHS 1018 124 62

Warning: the current number of heads per cylinder is 124
but the correct value may be 255.
You can use the Geometry menu to change this value.
It's something to try if
- some partitions are not found by TestDisk
- or the partition table can not be written because partitions overlaps.
```

```
$ sudo fdisk

Disk /dev/sda: 3.8 GiB, 4009754624 bytes, 7831552 sectors
Disk model: USB Flash Disk  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2be3e15c

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 7831551 7829504  3.8G  b W95 FAT32
```

after http://damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/setting_the_proper_geometry_on_your_usb_pendrive.html
is manual about it, however i do not feel like i have all important information from step 2

equation

```
   total_sectors / 32 / number_of_heads = no_of_cylinders.
```

it is written (fdisk) no_of_sectors = 7831552
it is said (testdisk) that no_of_heads suppose to be= 255

and according to equation above it suppose to be
7831552 / 32 = 244736
244736 / 255 = is 959.79401....
which is not round

other counting is round, but not proper, because it suppose to be 255...
244736 / 256 = 956

i am missing something simple, am i?

Comment: No OS/release details have been provided, why ask here?

Comment: What OS/release? We are talking here about the USBStick, which i can manage to run on Linux (any OS, like Ubuntu)

Comment: You hanve't said what OS/release you are trying to use, and this is not a generic Linux support site, so I'll refer you to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic which provides other SE sites for questions that don't meet requirements of this site.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Startup Disk Creator application in Ubuntu is good for making all kinds of bootable live USB sticks, not just for making Ubuntu live USBs. Whatever live USB you make with Startup Disk Creator will have no problem booting on Ubuntu or any other platform.